# Failed assertion: line 184 pos 12: 'end >= begin': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I solve the below error:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building AnimatedBuilder(animation: AnimationController#eedf7(▶ 0.111), dirty, state: _AnimatedState#2b432):
'package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart': Failed assertion: line 184 pos 12: 'end >= begin': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  AnimatedBuilder file:///Users/mahmoudalharoon/Desktop/FoodProject/makefood/lib/pizza/home/pizza_order_details.dart:331:9
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      Interval.transformInternal (package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart:184:12)
#3      ParametricCurve.transform (package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart:38:12)
#4      Curve.transform (package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart:92:18)
#5      CurvedAnimation.value (package:flutter/src/animation/animations.dart:453:24)
#6      _PizzaDetailsState._buildIngredientsWidget (package:makefood/pizza/home/pizza_order_details.dart:101:69)
...
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
'package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart': Failed assertion: line 184 pos 12: 'end >= begin': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  AnimatedBuilder file:///Users/mahmoudalharoon/Desktop/FoodProject/makefood/lib/pizza/home/pizza_order_details.dart:331:9
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building AnimatedBuilder(animation: AnimationController#eedf7(▶ 0.334), dirty, state: _AnimatedState#2b432):
'package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart': Failed assertion: line 184 pos 12: 'end >= begin': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  AnimatedBuilder file:///Users/mahmoudalharoon/Desktop/FoodProject/makefood/lib/pizza/home/pizza_order_details.dart:331:9
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      Interval.transformInternal (package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart:184:12)
#3      ParametricCurve.transform (package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart:38:12)
#4      Curve.transform (package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart:92:18)
#5      CurvedAnimation.value (package:flutter/src/animation/animations.dart:453:24)
#6      _PizzaDetailsState._buildIngredientsWidget (package:makefood/pizza/home/pizza_order_details.dart:101:69)
...
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
'package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart': Failed assertion: line 184 pos 12: 'end >= begin': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  AnimatedBuilder file:///Users/mahmoudalharoon/Desktop/FoodProject/makefood/lib/pizza/home/pizza_order_details.dart:331:9
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
'package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart': Failed assertion: line 184 pos 12: 'end >= begin': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  AnimatedBuilder file:///Users/mahmoudalharoon/Desktop/FoodProject/makefood/lib/pizza/home/pizza_order_details.dart:331:9
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
'package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart': Failed assertion: line 184 pos 12: 'end >= begin': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  AnimatedBuilder file:///Users/mahmoudalharoon/Desktop/FoodProject/makefood/lib/pizza/home/pizza_order_details.dart:331:9
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
'package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart': Failed assertion: line 184 pos 12: 'end >= begin': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  AnimatedBuilder file:///Users/mahmoudalharoon/Desktop/FoodProject/makefood/lib/pizza/home/pizza_order_details.dart:331:9
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building AnimatedBuilder(animation: AnimationController#eedf7(▶ 0.908), dirty, state: _AnimatedState#2b432):
'package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart': Failed assertion: line 184 pos 12: 'end >= begin': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  AnimatedBuilder file:///Users/mahmoudalharoon/Desktop/FoodProject/makefood/lib/pizza/home/pizza_order_details.dart:331:9
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      Interval.transformInternal (package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart:184:12)
#3      ParametricCurve.transform (package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart:38:12)
#4      Curve.transform (package:flutter/src/animation/curves.dart:92:18)
#5      CurvedAnimation.value (package:flutter/src/animation/animations.dart:453:24)
#6      _PizzaDetailsState._buildIngredientsWidget (package:makefood/pizza/home/pizza_order_details.dart:101:69)
...
====================================================================================================
```

and this is the error looks like as the below GIF

[image: error]

and this is the `_buildIngredientAnimation` method

```
void _buildIngredientAnimation() {
    _animationList.clear();
    _animationList.add(
      CurvedAnimation(
        curve: Interval(
          0.0,
          0.8,
          curve: Curves.decelerate,
        ),
        parent: _animationController,
      ),
    );
    _animationList.add(
      CurvedAnimation(
          curve: Interval(
            0.2,
            0.8,
            curve: Curves.decelerate,
          ),
          parent: _animationController),
    );
    _animationList.add(
      CurvedAnimation(
          curve: Interval(
            0.4,
            1.0,
            curve: Curves.decelerate,
          ),
          parent: _animationController),
    );
    _animationList.add(
      CurvedAnimation(
          curve: Interval(
            1.0,
            0.7,
            curve: Curves.decelerate,
          ),
          parent: _animationController),
    );
    _animationList.add(
      CurvedAnimation(
          curve: Interval(
            0.3,
            1.0,
            curve: Curves.decelerate,
          ),
          parent: _animationController),
    );
  }
```

and this is the build Widget method:

```
Widget _buildIngredientsWidget() {
    List<Widget> elements = [];
    if (_animationList.isNotEmpty) {
      for (int i = 0; i < _listIngredients.length; i++) {
        Ingredient ingredient = _listIngredients[i];
        final ingredientWidget = Image.asset(ingredient.image, height: 40);
        for (int j = 0; j < ingredient.positions.length; j++) {
          final animation = _animationList[j];
          final position = ingredient.positions[j];
          final positionX = position.dx;
          final positionY = position.dy;

          if (i == _listIngredients.length - 1) {
            double fromX = 0.0, fromY = 0.0;
            if (j < 1) {
              fromX = -_pizzaConstraints.maxWidth * (1 - animation.value);
            } else if (j < 2) {
              fromX = _pizzaConstraints.maxWidth * (1 - animation.value);
            } else if (j < 4) {
              fromY = -_pizzaConstraints.maxHeight * (1 - animation.value);
            } else {
              fromY = _pizzaConstraints.maxHeight * (1 - animation.value);
            }

            if (animation.value > 0) {
              elements.add(
                Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.identity()
                    ..translate(
                      fromX + _pizzaConstraints.maxWidth * positionX,
                      fromY + _pizzaConstraints.maxHeight * positionY,
                    ),
                  child: ingredientWidget,
                ),
              );
            }
          } else {
            elements.add(
              Transform(
                transform: Matrix4.identity()
                  ..translate(
                    _pizzaConstraints.maxWidth * positionX,
                    _pizzaConstraints.maxHeight * positionY,
                  ),
                child: ingredientWidget,
              ),
            );
          }
        }
      }
      return Stack(
        children: elements,
      );
    }
    return SizedBox.fromSize();
  }
```

and this is the below build method as I call the animated builder as the below code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: DragTarget<Ingredient>(
                onAccept: (ingredient) {
                  print('onAccept');
                  _notifierFocused.value = false;
                  setState(() {
                    _listIngredients.add(ingredient);
                    _total++;
                  });
                  _buildIngredientAnimation();
                  _animationController.forward(from: 0.0);
                },
                onWillAccept: (ingredient) {
                  print('onWillAccept');
                  _notifierFocused.value = true;
                  for (Ingredient i in _listIngredients) {
                    if (i.compare(ingredient)) {
                      return false;
                    }
                  }

                  return true;
                },
                onLeave: (ingredient) {
                  print('onLeave');
                  _notifierFocused.value = false;
                },
                builder: (context, list, rejects) {
                  return LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (context, constraints) {
                      _pizzaConstraints = constraints;
                      return Center(
                        child: ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
                            valueListenable: _notifierFocused,
                            builder: (context, focused, _) {
                              return AnimatedContainer(
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                                height: focused
                                    ? constraints.maxHeight
                                    : constraints.maxHeight - 10,
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: [
                                    Image.asset('assets/images/dish.png'),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                          'assets/images/pizza-1.png'),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            }),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            AnimatedSwitcher(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                return FadeTransition(
                  opacity: animation,
                  child: SlideTransition(
                    position: animation.drive(
                      Tween<Offset>(
                        begin: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                        end: Offset(0.0, animation.value),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: child,
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Text(
                '\$$_total',
                // key: Key(_total.toString()),
                key: UniqueKey(),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 26,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.cyan,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _animationController,
            builder: (context, _) {
              return _buildIngredientsWidget();
            }),
      ],
    );
```

this is the below full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:makefood/pizza/ingredient.dart';

const _pizzaCartSize = 55.0;

class PizzaOrderDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'New Order Pizza',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.cyan,
            fontSize: 29,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.add_shopping_cart,
              color: Colors.cyan,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            bottom: 50,
            right: 10,
            left: 10,
            child: Card(
              elevation: 10,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: _PizzaDetails(),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: _PizzaIngredients(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            height: _pizzaCartSize,
            width: _pizzaCartSize,
            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - _pizzaCartSize / 2,
            bottom: 25,
            child: _PizzaCartButton(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _PizzaDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PizzaDetailsState createState() => _PizzaDetailsState();
}

class _PizzaDetailsState extends State<_PizzaDetails>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final _listIngredients = List<Ingredient>();
  // final _listIngredients = <Ingredient>[];
  AnimationController _animationController;
  int _total = 15;
  final _notifierFocused = ValueNotifier(false);
  List<Animation> _animationList = <Animation>[];
  BoxConstraints _pizzaConstraints;

  Widget _buildIngredientsWidget() {
    List<Widget> elements = [];
    if (_animationList.isNotEmpty) {
      for (int i = 0; i < _listIngredients.length; i++) {
        Ingredient ingredient = _listIngredients[i];
        final ingredientWidget = Image.asset(ingredient.image, height: 40);
        for (int j = 0; j < ingredient.positions.length; j++) {
          final animation = _animationList[j];
          final position = ingredient.positions[j];
          final positionX = position.dx;
          final positionY = position.dy;
          double fromX = 0.0, fromY = 0.0;

          if (j < 1) {
            fromX = -_pizzaConstraints.maxWidth * (1 - animation.value);
          } else if (j < 2) {
            fromX = _pizzaConstraints.maxWidth * (1 - animation.value);
          } else if (j < 4) {
            fromY = -_pizzaConstraints.maxHeight * (1 - animation.value);
          } else {
            fromY = _pizzaConstraints.maxHeight * (1 - animation.value);
          }

          elements.add(
            Transform(
              transform: Matrix4.identity()
                ..translate(
                  fromX + _pizzaConstraints.maxWidth * positionX,
                  fromY + _pizzaConstraints.maxHeight * positionY,
                ),
              child: ingredientWidget,
            ),
          );
        }
      }
      return Stack(
        children: elements,
      );
    }
    return SizedBox.fromSize();
  }

  void _buildIngredientAnimation() {
    _animationList.clear();
    _animationList.add(CurvedAnimation(
      curve: Interval(0.0, 0.8, curve: Curves.decelerate),
      parent: _animationController,
    ));
    _animationList.add(CurvedAnimation(
      curve: Interval(0.2, 0.8, curve: Curves.decelerate),
      parent: _animationController,
    ));
    _animationList.add(CurvedAnimation(
      curve: Interval(0.4, 1.0, curve: Curves.decelerate),
      parent: _animationController,
    ));
    _animationList.add(CurvedAnimation(
      curve: Interval(1.0, 0.7, curve: Curves.decelerate),
      parent: _animationController,
    ));
    _animationList.add(CurvedAnimation(
      curve: Interval(0.3, 1.0, curve: Curves.decelerate),
      parent: _animationController,
    ));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 900),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: DragTarget<Ingredient>(
                onAccept: (ingredient) {
                  print('onAccept');
                  _notifierFocused.value = false;
                  setState(() {
                    _listIngredients.add(ingredient);
                    _total++;
                  });
                  _buildIngredientAnimation();
                  _animationController.forward(from: 0.0);
                },
                onWillAccept: (ingredient) {
                  print('onWillAccept');
                  _notifierFocused.value = true;
                  for (Ingredient i in _listIngredients) {
                    if (i.compare(ingredient)) {
                      return false;
                    }
                  }

                  return true;
                },
                onLeave: (ingredient) {
                  print('onLeave');
                  _notifierFocused.value = false;
                },
                builder: (context, list, rejects) {
                  return LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (context, constraints) {
                      _pizzaConstraints = constraints;
                      return Center(
                        child: ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
                            valueListenable: _notifierFocused,
                            builder: (context, focused, _) {
                              return AnimatedContainer(
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                                height: focused
                                    ? constraints.maxHeight
                                    : constraints.maxHeight - 10,
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: [
                                    Image.asset('assets/images/dish.png'),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                          'assets/images/pizza-1.png'),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            }),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            AnimatedSwitcher(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              // layoutBuilder: (Widget currentChild, List<Widget> previousChildren) {
              transitionBuilder: (child, animation) {
                return FadeTransition(
                  opacity: animation,
                  child: SlideTransition(
                    position: animation.drive(
                      Tween<Offset>(
                        begin: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                        end: Offset(0.0, animation.value),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: child,
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Text(
                '\$$_total',
                // key: Key(_total.toString()),
                key: UniqueKey(),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.cyan,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _animationController,
            builder: (context, child) {
              return _buildIngredientsWidget();
            }),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _PizzaCartButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          colors: [
            Colors.cyan.withOpacity(0.5),
            Colors.cyan,
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: Icon(
        Icons.shopping_bag_outlined,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 35,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _PizzaIngredients extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: ingredients.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final ingredient = ingredients[index];
        return _PizzaIngredientItem(ingredient: ingredient);
      },
    );
  }
}

class _PizzaIngredientItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const _PizzaIngredientItem({Key key, this.ingredient}) : super(key: key);
  final Ingredient ingredient;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final child = Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 45,
        width: 45,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFF5EED3),
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: Image.asset(
            ingredient.image,
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    return Center(
      child: Draggable(
        feedback: DecoratedBox(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 10.0,
              color: Colors.black26,
              offset: Offset(0.0, 5.0),
              spreadRadius: 10.0,
            ),
          ]),
          child: child,
        ),
        data: ingredient,
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here's also the ingredient class:

```
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class Ingredient {
  const Ingredient(this.image, this.positions);
  final String image;
  final List<Offset> positions;

  bool compare(Ingredient ingredient) => ingredient.image == image;
}

final ingredients = const <Ingredient>[
  Ingredient(
    'assets/images/chili.png',
    <Offset>[
      Offset(0.2, 0.2),
      Offset(0.6, 0.2),
      Offset(0.4, 0.25),
      Offset(0.5, 0.3),
      Offset(0.4, 0.65),
    ],
  ),
  Ingredient(
    'assets/images/garlic.png',
    <Offset>[
      Offset(0.2, 0.35),
      Offset(0.65, 0.35),
      Offset(0.3, 0.23),
      Offset(0.5, 0.2),
      Offset(0.3, 0.5),
    ],
  ),
  Ingredient(
    'assets/images/olive.png',
    <Offset>[
      Offset(0.25, 0.5),
      Offset(0.65, 0.6),
      Offset(0.2, 0.3),
      Offset(0.4, 0.2),
      Offset(0.2, 0.6),
    ],
  ),
  Ingredient(
    'assets/images/onion.png',
    <Offset>[
      Offset(0.2, 0.65),
      Offset(0.65, 0.3),
      Offset(0.25, 0.25),
      Offset(0.45, 0.35),
      Offset(0.4, 0.65),
    ],
  ),
  Ingredient(
    'assets/images/pea.png',
    <Offset>[
      Offset(0.2, 0.35),
      Offset(0.65, 0.35),
      Offset(0.3, 0.23),
      Offset(0.5, 0.2),
      Offset(0.3, 0.5),
    ],
  ),
  Ingredient(
    'assets/images/pickle.png',
    <Offset>[
      Offset(0.2, 0.65),
      Offset(0.65, 0.3),
      Offset(0.25, 0.25),
      Offset(0.45, 0.35),
      Offset(0.4, 0.65),
    ],
  ),
  Ingredient(
    'assets/images/potato.png',
    <Offset>[
      Offset(0.2, 0.2),
      Offset(0.6, 0.2),
      Offset(0.4, 0.25),
      Offset(0.5, 0.3),
      Offset(0.4, 0.65),
    ],
  ),
];
```

Comment: What value stored in `animation.value`?

Comment: @fartem I don't think the problem in `animation.value` part because it's related to the price text, I have posted the full code, can you have a check :)

Answer (score 2):

```
_animationList.add(
      CurvedAnimation(
          curve: Interval(
            1.0,
            0.7,
            curve: Curves.decelerate,
          ),
          parent: _animationController),
    );
```

Look at this code line the interval starts at 1.0 and ends at 0.7. End should always be greater than begin. I had the same error :) Hope this helps.